# Strange dictionary call?

Tags: python, dictionary

i'm troubleshooting a python script from another colleague who is away now. Python version is 2.6

I see the following:

```
self.connections = {}
[......]
#example device name
device_name = 'fedora'
self.devices = [device_name]
for dev in self.devices:  
    if self.connections[dev,'is_linux']:
        self.conn_ssh.switch_connection(dev)
```

can someone explain to me what the if statement evaluates?

I haven't seen this in python before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries can use tuples as keys, that's exactly what is happening there:

```
>>> d = {(1, 2): 100, ('a', 'b', 'c'): 1000}
>>> d[1, 2]
100
>>> d[(1, 2)]
100
>>> d['a', 'b', 'c']
1000
>>> d[('a', 'b', 'c')]
1000
```

Comma separated values are converted to a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

```
>>> 1, 2
(1, 2)
>>> 'a', 'b', 'c'
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Gotcha!, tuples with single items are represented with a trailing comma:

```
>>> t = 'a',  #or ('a',)
>>> type(t)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> t = ('a')  #Not a tuple   
>>> type(t)
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: So self.connections[dev,'is_linux'] is == self.connections[(dev,'is_linux')] ??

Comment: You're right!
Times like this i remember the "explicit is better than implicit" from the zen of python